# Difference in SELECT, WHERE and FROM subqueries

Tags: sql

Are there some rules of then to use a subquery in either SELECT, WHERE and FROM?
What is the difference when doing subqueries in these three, I do not understand the difference.

Or is it the same as a RIGHT JOIN, where we can write a RIGHT JOIN as a LEFT JOIN, i.e., they are all interchangable?

Answer (score 0):

For the most part a subquery can be used with a SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY or FROM clause.

Some issues arise when a subquery that returns more than one row while in an equality condition like this;

```
SELECT state_id, city
FROM city
WHERE state_id <> (SELECT state_id FROM states WHERE state <> 'Texas');

ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

You could use the IN keyword instead of the <>, or amend the ANY or ALL keywords (depending on need) to the equality statement.